# How the command "dns-fix" works?

Tags: command-line, dns

I had a problem on my DNS and after using this magical command, solved the problem. So I got curious: how this command, `dns-fix`, worked?

I am using the Mint distribution. The command is standard.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Mint `dns-fix` command (from searching) appears to be a [simple shell script](https://github.com/linuxmint/mintsystem/blob/master/usr/bin/dns-fix) that changes `/etc/resolv.conf` to use a few pre-defined nameservers.

You can confirm by using a file viewer to examine the script; e.g., `less "$(command -v dns-fix)"`.